# Powershell md5sum Alias

Tags: powershell

My goal is that i can type md5sum *file* in powershell.
I tried to add an alias see code below:

```
function file_hash {
  param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
    $algorithm,
    [Parameter(mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$true, Position = 1)]
    $file
  )
  if ($file) {
    (Get-FileHash -Path $file -Algorithm $algorithm).Hash
  }
}

Set-Alias md5sum (file_hash -algorithm 'MD5' -file $args)
```

Powershell can not create the alias because of the following error:
*Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Value' because it is null.*
Can someone help me out?
How can I get my md5sum alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you can’t do what you’re trying to do, at least not in the way you’re trying to do it.

From the Microsoft documentation at [Example 5: Create an alias for a command with parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias?view=powershell-7#example-5--create-an-alias-for-a-command-with-parameters):

> You cannot create an alias for a command with parameters and values, such as `Set-Location -Path C:\Windows\System32`.

The link above provides an alternative to achieve the same functionality though:

> To create an alias for a command, create a function that includes the command, and then create an alias to the function.

```bsh
PS> Function CD32 {Set-Location -Path C:\Windows\System32}

PS> Set-Alias -Name Go -Value CD32
```

So in your case you’d do something like:

```bsh
function Invoke-FileHashMD5
{
    param( $File )
    file_hash -algorithm 'MD5' -file $File
}

Set-Alias -Name md5sum -Value "Invoke-FileHashMD5"
```