# Issue with Setting Alias in PowerShell (oh-my-posh) on Windows 11

Tags: powershell, alias, powershell-cmdlet, windows-11, oh-my-posh

I'm facing an issue while trying to set an **alias** using PowerShell (oh-my-posh) on Windows 11. I have successfully created aliases before, like opening **Notepad++** using

```
Set-Alias np path_to_notepad_exe.
```

However, I'm having trouble creating a new alias to run `netsh wlan show profile` using

```
Set-Alias wsp 'netsh wlan show profile'
```

.

After updating the user_profile.ps1 file located at

```
C:\Users\CurrentUserAccount.config\powershell\user_profile.ps1
```

,
I encounter the following error when running the command **wsp** :

```
wsp
The term 'netsh wlan show profile' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

also , I've tried multiple approaches to resolve this issue:

1. I updated my `$PROFILE` and added this line of code to it:

```
New-Alias -Name wlan -Value "netsh wlan show profile"
```

2. I also attempted using a function definition like this:

```
function Show-WlanProfiles {
    netsh wlan show profile
}
```

I've ensured that the path is correct and tried different variations of the alias definition, but I can't seem to get it to work. What am I missing here? How can I properly set an alias for this command?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
[alias in user_profile.pa1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJLw5.jpg) 
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOaNY.jpg)

Comment: You can’t apply parameters in an alias - the best you can do is wrap the command in a function and create an alias for that. This is a multiple duplicate question - I’ll see if I can find a link to a previous one…

Comment: Here’s one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69072117/make-alias-in-powershell-to-run-the-command-that-may-include-further-parameters - but I’m pretty sure I’ve seen this same question multiple times over the years…

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/a/70828654/3156906 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63968913/powershell-md5sum-alias