# Pass argument to alias

Tags: powershell

I have created allias for kubernetes commands.

`$pods = kubectl get pod`

It works as intended, but what I can't manage is the following:

I want to create alias for kubectl describe pod, but still be able to pass the argument (pod name).

Example:

```
$pods_desc = kubectl describe pod 
$pods_desc my-pod-name
```

How can I pass pod name to the alias?

Comment: Do u want to script for bash or powershell?

Comment: You've not created an alias - the first line of code *executes* the command and returns the stdout text as a string. You also can't hard-code parameters - you'd need to wrap the command in a function to do that. There's other similar questions on this site - I'll see if I can find a link...

Comment: I need it for poweshell.

It returns string, if you use "". Without it returns the list of pods. It is actuali working fine, but i am not able to pass pod name as an argument

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73000204/3156906 https://stackoverflow.com/a/63969214/3156906

Comment: @gio.s I implemented it below and tested it, and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Powershell (works for only default namespace):**

```
function Get-PodDescription {
    param(
        [string]$podName
    )
    kubectl describe pod $podName 
}

New-Alias -Name pods_desc -Value Get-PodDescription
```

Test:

```
pods_desc <podname>
```

Remove alias:

```
$alias:pods_desc = $null
```

**Specific namespace:**

```
function Get-PodDescription {
    param(
        [string]$podName,
        [string]$namespace
    )

    kubectl describe pod $podName -n $namespace
}
New-Alias -Name pods_desc -Value Get-PodDescription
```

Run:

```
pods_desc <podname> <namespace>
```